# Change Sidedrawer content dynamically

Tags: nativescript

I´m at that point on my app, where the user Logged in, receive the data from the server and now i need to make same changes. One of the changes is change the button that appears on my Sidedrawer saying Log In to Log Out and vice-versa when the user Logs Out...I could talk about other changes but i think the main thing is...

How do I access the Sidedrawer content in order to change/add buttons. I already entered the `app-root.xml` and made same testing adding the `navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo"` function and also in the .js file just to see if it responds, but it doesn´t...

How do i perform this?

Comment: Ok i think i got it, i don´t know if it is the best pratctice but, just use the drawerOpening="onDrawerOpening" method inside the app-root.js and from here teste if it exists a Log In made or not, i´m thinking about saving the received token from the database in the appsettings and then on the above method just test if exists

Answer (score 2):

You can show/hide your button via ***visibility***, text binding or via a structural directive like ***ngIf** (if using **Angular**). For example, take a look [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/app.component.html#L11) - I am showing/hiding a button based on whether the user is logged in or not ([here is the related code-behind code](https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/app.component.ts#L147-L151)).

The above example is using an Angular directive and can be applied only in Angular based applications, but with the same logic, you can substitute ****ngIf*** with ***visibility*** and achieve the same in TypeScript or plain JavaScript app.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is put the frame inside drawer content area, then navigate frame to another page.